# Database of time lapse stem cell differentiation

Tags: database, stem-cells, systems-biology

Currently I am working on a project about modelling the social behaviours of embryonic stem cells (or induced pluripotent stem cells). I need a series of time-lapse live cell images which recording the stem cells behaviours in cell culture, also with markers showing the differentiation state of each cell. I wonder is there public resources of this kind of data?